# Downloading dataframe from databrick using display function

Tags: pandas, databricks

when downloading pandas from databricks using display function , getting

```
valueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring
```

how to handle this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Please check what pandas library are you using:

```
# THIS NOT: from pandas import read_csv
from pyspark.pandas import read_csv
pdf = read_csv("data.csv")
```

Since Spark 3.2 this new library is included. It is written on top of Spark API so your pandas will be executed in parallel on worker nodes not driver so it will be as native spark dataframes so should work correctly with display().

Warning: new pandas library coverage is around 90% of Pandas API so some of Pandas functions can be not supported.